# Jest collectCoverageFrom and coverageThreshold not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have simple create react app. I've created `jest.config.ts` file because my project is in typescript.

```
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";

// Sync object
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    collectCoverageFrom: ["./src/modules/*.tsx", "./src/hooks/*.tsx", "./src/components/*.tsx"],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            statements: 100,
            branches: 100,
            functions: 100,
            lines: 100,
        },
    },
};
export default config;
```

But when I run `npm t` or `npm run test --watch` my config `coverageThreshold` and `collectCoverageFrom` not working. I don't have an idea what's wrong.
Previously my config file have `js` extension, but I change its type because I think this is reason why it does not work.

Also I try to write instead of this  `collectCoverageFrom: ["./src/modules/*.tsx", "./src/hooks/*.tsx", "./src/components/*.tsx"],`

this one `collectCoverageFrom: ["**/src/modules/*.tsx", "**/src/hooks/*.tsx", "**/src/components/*.tsx"],`

and this one

`collectCoverageFrom: ["**/src/**/*.tsx"],`

But `jest.config` file doesn't work.

package.json

```
{
    "name": "ui",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.34",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
        // other libs
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "proxy": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"npm run mock\" ",
        "mock": "nodemon mock --watch mock",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "prettier": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write \"**/*.+(js|json)\"",
        "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .",
        "format": "npm run prettier -- --write",
        "check-format": "npm run prettier -- --list-different",
        "validate": "npm-run-all --parallel lint check-format build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
        "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
        // any other libs
    }
}
```

Also index.html file in coverage folder show coverage like this

> 60.6% **Statements** `20/33` 40% **Branches** `4/10` 46.66% **Functions** `7/15` 58.62% **Lines** `17/29`

This means when I run `npm t` jest must show me error about global coverage does not 100%. But I don't see any error in terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed this adding jest config to my package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
      "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
      "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
      "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
      // any other libs
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "src/components/*.tsx",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/src/test-utils/**",
      "!**/src/index.tsx"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
        "global": {
            "statements": 100,
            "branches": 100,
            "functions": 100,
            "lines": 100
        }
    }
  }
```